# Interdependent Comboboxes On Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I'm creating a Check In/Check Out System for tools and I'm trying to create basically a search function for the tools in a Userform.

The search criteria for them is Supplier, Brand, Part Number, Flutes, Cutting Diameter, Shank Diameter, Flute Length, and Overall Length.

There is a list on an excel spreadsheet with the available tools and all the information listed above in 8 columns. When the user opens the userform there are 8 comboboxes corresponding to the above search criteria. Each combobox has its list filled with the every option for that search criteria, with no duplicate values in the list (For Example: For Flutes, there are tools with 2 flutes and 3 flutes, so in the combobox for Flutes, the list would contain 2 and 3, there are multiple drills with 3 flutes and multiple drills with 2 flutes but it only includes 2 and 3 once in the list).

What I am having trouble with is having the other combobox lists filter each time a combobox value is changed. So when I enter 3 flutes into the flute combobox and 3 inches long for the overall length, I want the rest of the combobox lists to contain only the options for drills with 3 flutes that are 3 inches long. I am trying to be able to filter down the options for the user until there is only one option or multiple for certain criteria so the user has a choice. How is the best way of going about this? I've been struggling on this part for a while

Comment: Can you post your pseudo code so that we can help you?